# Angle rotation detector

Tags: android

I m trying to make an app that would show me at what angle my device is being rotate and also have a menu that would provide me option to see the result in degree or radian but after running this code only screen is being appeared showing the layout  and on rotating the device nothing is happening plzz tell me where i m wrong  Thanx in advance

```
package com.example.directordetector;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mInitialized = false;
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_name, menu);
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.degree:
        m = 0;
        return true;
    case R.id.radian:
        m = 1;
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView tvX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.x_axis);
    TextView tvY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.y_axis);
    TextView tvZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.z_axis);
    float x = event.values[0];
    float y = event.values[1];
    float z = event.values[2];
    if (!mInitialized) {
        mLastX = x;
        mLastY = y;
        mLastZ = z;
        tvX.setText("0.0");
        tvY.setText("0.0");
        tvZ.setText("0.0");
        mInitialized = true;
    } else {
        float deltaX = Math.abs(mLastX - x);
        float deltaY = Math.abs(mLastY - y);
        float deltaZ = Math.abs(mLastZ - z);
        if (deltaX < NOISE)
            deltaX = (float) 0.0;

        if (deltaY < NOISE)
            deltaY = (float) 0.0;

        if (deltaZ < NOISE)
            deltaZ = (float) 0.0;
        mLastX = x;
        mLastY = y;
        mLastZ = z;
        if (m == 1) {

            deltaX = (float) (deltaX * (3.18 / 180));
            deltaX = (float) (deltaX * (3.18 / 180));
            deltaX = (float) (deltaX * (3.18 / 180));
        }

        tvX.setText(Float.toString(deltaX));
        tvY.setText(Float.toString(deltaY));
        tvZ.setText(Float.toString(deltaZ));

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I can't tell why it wouldn't be working. But I would suggest you not make the findViewById() calls be inside your sensor listener callback. That method is fairly expensive, and your sensor callback is going to receive LOTS of calls.

Declare your Views in the activity, and instantiate them in onCreate() like this:

```
TextView tvX;
TextView tvY;
TextView tvZ;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tvX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.x_axis);
    tvY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.y_axis);
    tvZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.z_axis);
    ...
}
```

That way you are only calling findViewById() once, and you will always be able to use your references to change the text in the TextViews.

When you run what you have now what exactly happens? Do the TextViews get set to "0.0" and stay that way? Or do they not get set at all?

Answer (score 0):

findViewById() belongs in onCreate() method ( I also wrote small library which 
would perform dependency injection for views and some other thingies: https://github.com/ko5tik/andject )

And accelerometer is wrong sensor for rotation - you can detect movement or tilting of device, but not rotation around of one of the device axes.  Use magnet field sensor for this

Comment: It does not provide you with rotation information. Only direction of acceleration of device.

Comment: accelerometer will not show me angle of rotation means at what angle my device has been rotated??